# NSURLErrorDomain: Could not connect to the server

Tags: ios, wiremock

I'm following this tutorial to a better understanding of UI test automation and API server mockup: https://marcosantadev.com/run-swift-ui-tests-mock-api-server/

I have correctly setup launched the local server, using `WireMock`:

[image]

I have also added the allowing insecure HTTP loads lines in `Info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But later when I'm launching the tests, I'm getting this error:

```
Binding error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2825bd2f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:1234/users, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:1234/users, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

iOS requires a secure URL. Update your webserver so you can use an https address with an ssl certificate and you should be good to go.